# Nextbook drivers for windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers

I reformatted my Inter Nextbook 10.1 tablet with keyboard, but the drivers wont install automatically.

So I cannot use the touch or any of the usual functions.

I downloaded the files from http://www.nextbookusa.com/download.php, but I cannot get anything to run.

I hope anybody else has had this trouble before and can help me get the drivers to load.

---

The files that I tried to run wanted to completely reset the nextbook, because they are firmware drivers, I simply want to install the necessary drivers so that I will be able to use the nextbook

Comment: `but I cannot get anything to run.` Can you specify what happens if you try to run them? Do you get an error message? Are they .inf files which you may need to right click? etc etc. As it stands we simply do not have enough information to answer.

Comment: I updated the question now, I simply want to install drivers, not do any reset/refresh

Comment: Do you have a working mouse and/or a USB mouse you can plug in and have it work?  Once you have a working mouse you should be able to download, and install with a mouse alone.

Comment: the nextbooks I have does have an attachable keyboard with trackpad, all is working with the, but it does not want to automatically download the drivers, am I looking past a file in the downloads that is supposed to be the drivers?

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, you and many others (Including myself), have purchased a lemon. I have the same problem and have searched high and low for the original drivers for this machine. I have contacted Nextbook about this issue 3 times only to get the same answer.

OK! I finally found what we are looking for!
I have used these files and have FULL function back on my Flexx !!
Originally posted by Russell Hande in [Microsoft Community Forums - Installing Windows 10 on the Nextbook 10.1](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_install/installing-windows-10-on-the-nextbook-101-that-is/18a49db3-ad1e-4232-aa44-547409a27518?page=2&auth=1).

Follow these instructions:

Everything you need for the Nextbook 10.1 can be found on:
https://archive.midnightchannel.net/zefie/files/atom_z3735g_tablet/drivers/.
The sensor.7z file contains a registry file which will, after reboot, fix the orientation sensor.

sensor.7z contains the orientation sensor driver and registry config. Run the EXE, then run the reg file, then reboot.

chipset.rar contains the processor and chipset drivers. This enables the SD Card, Touch panel, and other various system resources. Extract, then navigate to ww30PV-with-LED\mrd7-pv-ww30-led\ww30\DriverPackage\Installer\PlatformInstaller\ and run setup.exe.

wifi.rar contains the wifi driver
bluetooth.rar contains the bluetooth driver

These drivers will work on Windows 8.1 and 10.

I used these drivers on my Flexx 11 and restored all functions.

Comment: This is great commentary just not an answer